# Why is the border hidden when using position:relative and a background color?

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/eh7nv8t0/2/

CSS:

```
table.inner {
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
table tr td {
  position: relative;
    border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
}


.bg{
  background:#ddd;

}
```

HTML:

```
<table class="inner">
<tr>
<td>4341123</td>
<td>4343</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="bg">4341123</td>
<td>4343</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4341123</td>
<td>4343</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please provide more details of your issue, the JSFiddle you posted shows a border in both, what are you aiming for?

Comment: Border is finely displaying in your code.

Comment: in what browser are you facing this issue? can you show a screenshot?

Comment: @TemaniAfif https://i.imgur.com/d1xaCXF.png firefox latest. It was solved, I marked an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `padding-box` to your `.bg` `background` property:

```
.bg {
  background: #ddd padding-box;
}
```

See the snippet below:

```css
table.outer {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.inner {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr td {
  position: relative;
}

table tr td {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
}

.bg {
  background: #ddd padding-box;
}
```

```html
<table class="outer">
  <tr>
    <td>

      <table class="inner">
        <tr>
          <td>4341123</td>
          <td>4343</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4341123</td>
          <td>4343</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="bg">4341123</td>
          <td>4343</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>

      <table class="inner">
        <tr>
          <td>4341123</td>
          <td>4343</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4341123</td>
          <td>4343</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="bg">4341123</td>
          <td>4343</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The border isn't really hidden.

Rather position:relative causes the content to not be adjusted to the normal position and therefore it overflows the border. This is due to the fact that the border is inside the block element, exactly where your backgroud color is.

As Kosh already mentioned you can get rid of this feature by shirinking the box to it's padding-size via *padding-box*